# How can I operate with the output of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `DataFrame` object and I'm grouping by some keys and counting the results. The problem is that I want to replace one of the index of the DataFrame columns for a relation between the counts.

```
df.groupby(['A','B', 'C'])['C'].count().apply(f).reset_index()
```

I'm looking for an `f` that replaces the column `C` by the value of `#timesC==1 / #timesC==0` for each value of `A` and `B`.

Comment: So you should groupby ['A','B'] rather than ['A','B','C']?

Comment: Please supply a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your question

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
     {'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3],
      'B':[2,0,1,2,0,1],
      'C':[1,1,0,1,1,1]
      })
print(df)

def f(x):
    if np.count_nonzero(x==0)==0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return np.count_nonzero(x==1)/np.count_nonzero(x==0)

result = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].apply(f).reset_index()
print(result)
```

Result:

```
#df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  2  0  1
2  3  1  0
3  1  2  1
4  2  0  1
5  3  1  1

#result
   A  B    C
0  1  2  NaN
1  2  0  NaN
2  3  1  1.0
```